# "Reboot and select proper Boot device" for the 2nd time

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, grub2, bootrepair

I have been using Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7 for quite some time now. A few weeks back I got the error message below, but surprisingly I was able to boot again after few days. Yesterday it crashed again.

```
 Boot Info Script e7fc706 + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info 9Feb2015]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================


============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

no valid partition table found
"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sr0                                                iso9660    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS amd64

========================= "ls -l /dev/disk/by-id" output: ======================

total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jan 18 16:29 ata-MATSHITADVD-RAM_UJ8E2_S_H090_449177 -> ../../sr0

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sr0         /cdrom                   iso9660    (ro,noatime)



ADDITIONAL INFORMATION :
=================== log of boot-repair 2016-01-18__16h55 ===================
boot-repair version : 4ppa35
boot-sav version : 4ppa35
glade2script version : 3.2.2~ppa45~precise
boot-sav-extra version : 4ppa35
boot-repair is executed in live-session (Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS, precise, Ubuntu, x86_64)
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash -- maybe-ubiquity
ls: cannot access /home/usr/.config: No such file or directory

=================== os-prober:


=================== blkid:
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sr0: LABEL="Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660"


=================== UEFI/Legacy mode:
This live-session is not in EFI-mode.
SecureBoot maybe enabled.


=================== PARTITIONS & DISKS:



=================== parted -l:

Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0 has been opened read-only.
Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!

=================== parted -lm:

Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0 has been opened read-only.
Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!

=================== lsblk:
KNAME TYPE FSTYPE     SIZE LABEL
sr0   rom  iso9660    758M Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS amd64
loop0 loop squashfs 712.6M

KNAME ROTA RO RM STATE   MOUNTPOINT
sr0      1  0  1 running /cdrom
loop0    1  1  0         /rofs


=================== mount:
/cow on / type overlayfs (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
/dev/sr0 on /cdrom type iso9660 (ro,noatime)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/ubuntu/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=ubuntu)


=================== ls:
/sys/block/sr0 (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/dev (filtered):  autofs block bsg btrfs-control bus cdrom cdrw char console core cpu cpu_dma_latency cuse disk dri dvd dvdrw ecryptfs fb0 fd full fuse hpet input kmsg libmtp-1-2 log mapper mcelog mei mem net network_latency network_throughput null port ppp psaux ptmx pts random rfkill rtc rtc0 sg0 shm snapshot snd sr0 stderr stdin stdout uhid uinput urandom v4l vga_arbiter vhci vhost-net video0 zero
ls /dev/mapper:  control

=================== df -Th:

Filesystem     Type       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/cow           overlayfs  3.9G  169M  3.7G   5% /
udev           devtmpfs   3.9G   12K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs      787M  856K  787M   1% /run
/dev/sr0       iso9660    758M  758M     0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0     squashfs   713M  713M     0 100% /rofs
tmpfs          tmpfs      3.9G   32K  3.9G   1% /tmp
none           tmpfs      5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none           tmpfs      3.9G  600K  3.9G   1% /run/shm

=================== fdisk -l:



Error: no partitions


=================== Suggested repair
The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.


=================== User settings
The settings chosen by the user will not act on the boot.




pastebinit  packages needed
W: Duplicate sources.list entry cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20140807.1)/ precise/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/Ubuntu%2012.04.5%20LTS%20%5fPrecise%20Pangolin%5f%20-%20Release%20amd64%20(20140807.1)_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20140807.1)/ precise/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/Ubuntu%2012.04.5%20LTS%20%5fPrecise%20Pangolin%5f%20-%20Release%20amd64%20(20140807.1)_dists_precise_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or directory
```

Comment: No one guys????

Comment: Gparted shows "No devices detected". Guys I'm desperate!